# less css grid settup

Tags: grid, less

I'm creating less grid sistem and i dont know how to optimise grid.less
If i chouse @gridColumns: 14; i need to add new lines in grid.less, maybe there is anothes option to automate this?

**Variables.less**

```
@gridColumns: 12;
@gridWidth: 62.5em;
@gridGutterWidth: 1.8em;
```

**@grid.less**

```
.l-1         { .grid(1); }
.l-2         { .grid(2); }
.l-3         { .grid(3); }
.l-4         { .grid(4); }
.l-5         { .grid(5); }
.l-6         { .grid(6); }
.l-7         { .grid(7); }
.l-8         { .grid(8); }
.l-9         { .grid(9); }
.l-10        { .grid(10); }
.l-11        { .grid(11); }
.l-12        { .grid(12); }
```

**@mixins.less**

```
.grid(@num) {
width: (100% / @gridColumns) * @num;
position: relative;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sensible way of doing it using LESS is using a [recursive mixin like Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L573).

```
.spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  .span@{index} { .span(@index); }
  .spanX(@index - 1);
}
.spanX (0) {}

.span (@columns) {
  width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1));
}
```

Comment: Im beginer with less, maybe you can give me some eplanations how to create this sistem correcly with // comments? Thanks